# Dynamic allocation of objects with aligned members - possible solutions?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, sse, memory-alignment

I'm considering using SSE to speed up some code in my project. This usually requires 16 byte alignment of data I'm working on. For static allocation I suppose `__declspec(align(16))` solves the problem but my problem is: what's the best way to make sure that is the case when doing dynamic allocations? Especially in cases where allocated object does not directly require alignment but uses objects with alignment requirement as members (thus making it much easier to forget about making sure it's properly aligned). I came up with following solutions:

1. Always assume that any potentially non-statically allocated data is unaligned and use unaligned load instructions. From what I've read this is slow and it might be not worth to bother with SSE at all in this case. I can implement that and test how it performs but I'd rather ask about better solutions before I put so much work into it just to find out that it's not worth it or that there is another solution.
2. Be very careful and use only `_aligned_malloc`/`_aligned_free` to allocate any object that requires alignment and any object that uses those as members. This is probably very easy to forget and thus error prone.
3. Overload `new`/`delete` globally and/or create custom `malloc`/`free` functions that align memory and then use those for everything. However it's probably not the best idea to literally align *everything* that is dynamically allocated.
4. Create a base class with overloaded `new`/`delete` operators then make sure that any class that requires alignment and any class that uses those as members inherits it. Then just use `new`/`delete` for most/all dynamic allocations. Probably less error prone then 2.
5. Some other way I didn't think of or I'm not aware of?

Options 1.-3. are a probably not the best ideas. What about 4.? Am I wrong about anything I mentioned? Suggestions, opinions, useful links on this topic?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Why don't you just align the members that need it? Makes live easier.

Comment: If I understand you (and how `__declspec(align)` or similar work) correctly then this wouldn't change much. If I have a class `Foo` that needs to be aligned I would use `__declspec(align(16))` in its definition which would align it properly for all _static_ allocations without the need for explicit alignment when used as a member of class `Bar`. This doesn't change anything for dynamic allocation though and I would have to use one of the solutions I mentioned for both `Foo` and `Bar` and any other class that uses either of those as members.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, malloc is 16-byte aligned ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ycsb6wwf.aspx)). If your platform malloc has lower alignment requirements, you need to use aligned versions of malloc for objects used by SSE.

EDIT: If you have a specific class of objects that need SSE support you can redefine new/delete for that class only.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I didn't know that, sadly apparently this is only true for 64-bit platform, when compiled for 32-bits `malloc` aligns to 8 bytes and changing it's default behavior to 16 would probably impact performance negatively on 32-bit platforms. Yes, I'm afraid that "cleanest" and safest solution is to just overload `new`/`delete` for all classes that use SSE either directly or through one of their members, and using new (for me) information from your link just disable that code when compiling for 64-bit platforms.

Comment: @CuriousCppUser And don't forget to provide a custom allocator to any standard containers for aligned objects, as the default allocator just calls the global `operator new`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is practical for your purposes, but you could employ [Doug Lea's allocator](http://g.oswego.edu/) and define MALLOC_ALIGNMENT macro to suit your needs (up to 128bytes).

You don't even need to replace the default allocator - you should be able to use Doug Lea-specific `dlmalloc` and `dlfree` for your SSE needs only, and continue to use default allocator for everything else.